# Postgres syntax error at or near "FILTER"

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, group-by

I use PostgreSQL version 12.1 by my local machine and wrote query

```
SELECT cit.id, cit.city, cit.google_sheet_links,
COALESCE(json_agg(
  json_build_object(
      'id', c_sch.id, 
      'name', c_sch.name,
      'animation', c_sch.animation,
      'headerBgColor', c_sch.header_color_bg,
      'headerTextColor', c_sch.header_color_text,
      'headerText', c_sch.header_text,
      'bodyBgColor', c_sch.body_color_bg,
      'bodyCurrencyColor', c_sch.body_color_currency,
      'bodyNumbersColor', c_sch.body_color_numbers,
      'bodyHeadersColor', c_sch.body_color_headers,
      'footerBgColor', c_sch.footer_color_bg,
      'footerColor', c_sch.footer_color_text,
      'footerText', c_sch.footer_text
    )
  )
FILTER (WHERE c_sch.id IS NOT NULL), '[]') AS screens
FROM public.cities cit LEFT JOIN public.color_schemes c_sch
ON c_sch.city_id = cit.id
GROUP BY cit.id;
```

but server using postgresql version 9.2.24 and when i want to use current query i get an error.

```
error: syntax error at or near "FILTER"
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) - you should not use that version anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `filter` extension for aggregate functions was added in Postgres 9.4 (which was released in 2014).

In earlier versions, you can use a conditional expression within the aggregate function, like:

```
json_agg(
    case when c_sch.id is not null
        then json_build_object(
            'id', c_sch.id, 
            'name', c_sch.name,
            'animation', c_sch.animation,
            'headerBgColor', c_sch.header_color_bg,
            'headerTextColor', c_sch.header_color_text,
            'headerText', c_sch.header_text,
            'bodyBgColor', c_sch.body_color_bg,
            'bodyCurrencyColor', c_sch.body_color_currency,
            'bodyNumbersColor', c_sch.body_color_numbers,
            'bodyHeadersColor', c_sch.body_color_headers,
            'footerBgColor', c_sch.footer_color_bg,
            'footerColor', c_sch.footer_color_text,
            'footerText', c_sch.footer_text
        )
    end
)
```

However, please note that, as commented by Nick Barnes, `json_agg()` does not ignore `null`s (unlike other standard aggregate functions such as `min()`, `max()` and so on), so the above query will not produce the exact same result as when using the `filter` clause.

One solution would be to move the aggregation to a subquery instead:

```
select
    cit.id, 
    cit.city, 
    cit.google_sheet_links,
    (
        select coalesce(
            json_agg(
                json_build_object(
                    'id', c_sch.id, 
                    'name', c_sch.name,
                    'animation', c_sch.animation,
                    'headerBgColor', c_sch.header_color_bg,
                    'headerTextColor', c_sch.header_color_text,
                    'headerText', c_sch.header_text,
                    'bodyBgColor', c_sch.body_color_bg,
                    'bodyCurrencyColor', c_sch.body_color_currency,
                    'bodyNumbersColor', c_sch.body_color_numbers,
                    'bodyHeadersColor', c_sch.body_color_headers,
                    'footerBgColor', c_sch.footer_color_bg,
                    'footerColor', c_sch.footer_color_text,
                    'footerText', c_sch.footer_text
                )
            ),
            '[]'
        )
        from public.color_schemes c_sch
        where c_sch.id is not null and c_sch.city_id = cit.id
    ) screens
from public.cities cit;
```

Comment: Works for aggregates like `sum()`/`count()` which ignore `null` inputs, but `json_agg()` will include them in the array, so this is not quite the same as a `filter`

Comment: @NickBarnes: ah yes, you are right. Let me improve this.

Comment: @NickBarnes: done. Hopefully this should be functionaly equivalent to the original query now.

Comment: @GMB But now i have and error 

ERROR:  function json_build_object(unknown, integer, unknown, character varying, unknown, character varying, unknown, character varying, unknown, character varying, unknown, character varying, unknown, character varying, unknown, character varying, unknown, character varying, unknown, character varying, unknown, character varying, unknown, character varying, unknown, character varying) does not exist
LINE 8:                 json_build_object(
                        ^

Comment: @OlegOvcharenko: `json_build_object()` does not exist in 9.2. It doesn't look like `json_agg()` exists either. You *really* need to upgrade...

Answer (score 0):

seems you missed  a ) before FILTER

```
SELECT cit.id, cit.city, cit.google_sheet_links,
COALESCE(json_agg(
  json_build_object(
      'id', c_sch.id, 
      'name', c_sch.name,
      'animation', c_sch.animation,
      'headerBgColor', c_sch.header_color_bg,
      'headerTextColor', c_sch.header_color_text,
      'headerText', c_sch.header_text,
      'bodyBgColor', c_sch.body_color_bg,
      'bodyCurrencyColor', c_sch.body_color_currency,
      'bodyNumbersColor', c_sch.body_color_numbers,
      'bodyHeadersColor', c_sch.body_color_headers,
      'footerBgColor', c_sch.footer_color_bg,
      'footerColor', c_sch.footer_color_text,
      'footerText', c_sch.footer_text
    )
  )
)
FILTER (WHERE c_sch.id IS NOT NULL), '[]') AS screens
FROM public.cities cit LEFT JOIN public.color_schemes c_sch
ON c_sch.city_id = cit.id
GROUP BY cit.id;
```

or you need  some value for coalesce and then a ) before FILTER

Comment: Thanks for answer. My query work in postgress version 12.1 but don't work in version 9.2.24

Comment: The FILTER clause start from Postgres 9.4  released in December 2014

Comment: @scaisEdge: The `FILTER` clause needs to directly follow the aggregate call. The closing `)` for the `COALESCE` is after the `FILTER`. This is intentional; the output of the (filtered) aggregate is the thing being coalesced, e.g.: https://rextester.com/UNCS37245